# make subsets of data based on percentages

Tags: r, subset, cross-validation

I Have a dataset that contains repeated measures(3 timepoints), what I would like to do is create 5 subsets of my current dataset. The dataset consists of 5 treatment levels that contain unequal rows (i.e. on level has 25 rows the other 23).

I have managed to calculate the ratio of each level and now I would like to make 5 new subsets of the data based on the ratios.

some example code:

```
effect.Treatment #dataframe contains 393 rows(131 unique individuals)
nrows <- nrow(df.data)
treatment1 <- subset(effect.Treatment, red.intervention == 1)
treatment2 <- subset(effect.Treatment, red.intervention == 2)
treatment3 <- subset(effect.Treatment, red.intervention == 3)
treatment4 <- subset(effect.Treatment, red.intervention == 4)
treatment5 <-  subset(effect.Treatment, red.intervention == 5)

#ratio of treatmens
per.treatment1 < -round(nrow(treatment1 )/nrow(nrows), digits=2)
per.treatment2 <- round(nrow(treatment2 )/nrow(nrows), digits=2)
per.treatment3 <- round(nrow(treatment3 )/nrow(nrows), digits=2)
per.treatment4 <-round( nrow(treatment4 )/nrow(nrows), digits=2)
per.treatment5 <-round( nrow(treatment5 )/nrow(nrows), digits=2)
percentages <- c(treatment1 , per.treatment2, per.treatment3, per.treatment4, per.treatment5)
```

So, now I have a vector  percentages that contains for each level the ratio.

I would now like to make 5 subsets of the original dataframe based on the percentages vector

Answer (score 0):

We could make this faster if you do a group by operation and keep it in a single dataset

```
library(dplyr)
effect.treatment %>%
     group_by(red.intervention) %>%
     summarise(across(starts_with('treatment'),
       ~ round(n()/nrow(.), digits = 2),
              .names = 'per.{col}'), .groups = 'drop')
```

It is not recommended to create multiple objects in the global environment.

---

Or with `aggregate`

```
sub_cols <- c('red.intervention', grep('^treatment', names(effect.treatment)))
aggregate(.~ red.intervention, 
    effect.treatment[sub_cols], 
                  function(x) round(length(x)/nrow(x), digits = 2))
```

Comment: I am getting an error that the methode across does not exists even though i called dplyr

Comment: @Hedayat please check `packageVersion('dplyr')`. `across` is from `dplyr` 1.0.0 onwards